# TypeScript error TS2349 after upgrading from 2.7.x to 2.8.x

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

After upgrading from TypeScript 2.7.x to 2.8.1 I get following error for all my jQuery calls (either in `.ts` and in `.js` files) using `$` (like `$(selector).text('Amiga Forever')`, which I did not get with version 2.7:

`error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof $' has no compatible call signatures.`

I did not change anything in the code, just upgraded the TypeScript compiler. I use `"@types/jquery": "^2.0.49"` in my `package.json`. Upgrading to latest jQuery types does not help.

**EDIT:**

Here is a code sample. My code is structured with just namespaces but no modules:

```js
namespace My.Controller {

    export class TextController extends ControllerBase {

        constructor() {
            super();
        }

        public setText(text: string) {

            $(this._textSelector).text(text);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

This is a screenshot of the message I get in Visual Studio Code, when I hover `$`:
[image]

And here is my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "none",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist"
    },
    "include": [
         "source/**/*",
         "source/index.html"
    ]
}
```

I also tried to add the types to the compiler options (see below) which does not help either:

```
"types": [
    "jquery"
]
```

**EDIT3:**

The problem occurs through extending jQuery functionality within a `.js` file instead of using a `.ts` file. See the accepted answer for details.
But it stays unclear, why the behavior changed from TS 2.7.x to TS 2.8.x

Comment: I've tried myself, and with TypeScript 2.8.1 and `@types/jquery` 3.3.1 there is no problem, it works perfectly. In fact, then I tried with your same version of types and works well, too.

Comment: @OscarPaz Thanks fpr trying. Hm ... Do you use import or `///<reference path=` or sth to include the jQuery types? I alter my question with a more explicit code example in some minutes.

Comment: No, it is not necessary to use references. TypeScript automatically loads types from `node_modules\@types`, except you tell it not to. Two questions: does VSCode notify you of the error, or you only get it when you compile? And, can you post your `tsconfig.json` file? Oh, and maybe if you could post what VSCode tells you `$` is when  you hover over it would help, I think

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought and what worked, not using references. VSCode shows me the problem(s) under the "PROBLEMS" view, like `[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof $' has no compatible call signatures.` I will update my post with tsconfig and "hovering over $".

Comment: It says `var $: typeof $`? What the hell? It should say `var $: JQueryStatic`. It seems something is overwriting `$`. Can you select the `$` in the editor, open the context menu and select `go to definition'? And then post the name of the file and the code where `$`  is defined

Comment: `typeof`: Yeah, that irritated my, too. But ... thankfully you pointed my to the right direction, thanks a lot! I have a `.js` file where I define some jQuery extensions like so:
`$.fn.doesExist = function () { return jQuery(this).length > 0; };`
THIS leads to the strange typeof error. If I comment that out, it works. So, question would be how to do that in the right way (and why TS2.8 has problems with that).

Comment: I'll post a response for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly know why TypeScript 2.8 protests about that. Maybe it has improved the way they infer types from JavaScript files.

Now, to add extensions to JQuery in TypeScript, is easy. For examply, the `doesExist` method:

First, you need a **declaration file** in which you declare your changes. For example, `jquery-custom.d.ts`.

In that file, we modify the interface `JQuery`, and, thanks to TypeScript merging declarations, we end up with an interface with all methods:

```
declare interface JQuery {
    doesExist: () => boolean
    // ... other custom methods ...
}
```

Now, you're telling TypeScript that `JQuery` objects have a `doesExist` method. Of course, we need to really define that method or we'll run into runtime errors. So we add another file (you can't add sentences in ambient declaration files), jquery-custom.ts:

```
$.fn.doesExist = function(): boolean {
    return this.length > 0;
}
```

You have to import the `jquery-custom.ts` in the entry point of your application (`import './jquery-custom.ts'`) and you can use the extension safely. You don't need to import the `d.ts` file, because TypeScript recognises them implicitly, just like it does with those under `node_modules/@types`.

This way, you can get rid of the JavaScript file in which you had those extensions previously, and you gain better type-checking.

Hope this serves you!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped! The "funny" thing is: I already had that `jquery-custom.d.ts` file (but I forgot to mention it, sorry :-( ). In order to make it work I had to rename my `.js` file to `.ts` like you mentioned and to include the definition with '<reference path />`. `import` does not work here; it breaks my code (`[ts] Namespace 'XYZ' as no exported member 'Controller'.` but that is subject of a different topic. :-))

Comment: Glad to be of help. These 'programming poltergeists' are annoying but when you fix them is rewarding :-)